How to use a custom DB logger with TypeORM?
I am using TypeORM and NestJS.  The default TypeORM logger seems to not log in JSON output format, which is what I want.
How can I create a custom DB logger that allows me to customise how I want to present those JSON-logs for the pre- and the post (i.e. the DB-request and the DB-response), with e.g. meta-info like duration, etc. ?
It looks like one of the recommended approaches to do this would be to use some sort of existing typeorm logging interface?
